# What happened to the Doll disruption tech?

Tags: technology, dollhouse

In Dollhouse, what happened to the Doll disrupter?  That device Topher builds in the middle of season 2 that drops any Doll "in a 10 ft radius."  **crash**  "Make that a 50 ft radius."

Why didn't Topher build a bunch of those for the actuals to use once all hell breaks loose? Is an explanation for this ever given or are we supposed to just assume he lost it too fast?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, I'm pretty sure that the tech took down anyone with "Active architecture", meaning people whose brains had been conditioned to accept wipes and imprints.

When all hell broke loose, it was because of tech that could imprint without Active architecture, so it's likely the doll disruption tech was essentially useless at that point.

Answer (score 6):

To add a few thoughts in addition to [@Saalon's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/what-happened-to-the-doll-disruption-tech/1533#1533):

I just think that the implication was that after destroying Rassum's headquarters, the main characters did whatever they could to destroy and hide the dollhouse technology.  So that could explain why they didn't pursue mind-wiping defenses.

In addition, it seems that the characters didn't have the capacity to mass manufacture more Dollhouse technology nor did they want to.  The shear number of "Butchers" may have been just too many for the characters to feel that making and using disruptors was worth it.

Also, the disruptors may have interfered with how Victor and his cyber-mercenaries function.  They constantly uploaded new skills to their brains, so a disruption might have a negative effect on them.